# How to make text selection fit to complete word in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to make the text selection span complete words just like how  http://www.apture.com/ does. To be precise, if you start the selection in the middle of a word, it should include the entire word.

For example, if my text is like this:

"This is some sa**mple te**xt for selection"

where the text in bold is selected using mouse, then it should cover the entire word making the selection look like

"This is some **sample text** for selection"

I came across this post --> [Expand selected text by one word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042273/expand-selected-text-by-one-word) which is exactly my same question but the solution does not work for all cases.

jQuery's wrapselection plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/wrapSelection is able to do it but I don't want to use the entire plugin. I just need simple logic/code sample to do this.

Comment: Unless you're targeting the 56k modem world, use wrapSelection since it works. If you really need to find out how it spins it's magic, grab firebug (firefox plugin) and a non-minified version of wrapSelection and step through it.

Comment: @Brandon My javascript is like already several KB and I don't want to make it much bigger so that my clients won't see any delay when they include my script. Moreover, wrapSelection plugin has a copyright to their code and there is no mention of any opensource licences or terms of use. So I am looking for some simple logic to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember who said it but 'worry about performance speeds only when you can see it's a problem'.

Hence, I would go with Brandon's suggestion of just using wrapSelection - it works, and minified it's 15K. Concatenate all your scripts into one file that's included at the bottom of the HTML, and by the time the user goes to select something the file will be downloaded.